# Load accessor Func by reflection into Dictionary

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Background: the user should be able to as efficiently reasonable as possible choose a DB-Table/Model/Class and filter/sort/display all of the public properties of it.

The names can be queried by the reflection-API, but I wondered, if these accesses can be stored and become more efficient this way?

This example shows how it could be done, however on every access it'll query the reflection-api in the func.

```
public class TestClass // the Model or Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void Main( string[] args )
{
    var testClasses = new TestClass[] {
        new TestClass { Id = 1 , Name = "1" } ,
        new TestClass { Id = 2 , Name = "2" } ,
        new TestClass { Id = 3 , Name = "3" } ,
    };

    var propertyInfos = typeof( TestClass ).GetProperties();
    var map = new Dictionary<string,Func<object,object>>(); // Func<object,object> -> Func takes an instance of the class and return a public property

    // load the map once
    foreach( var propertyInfo in propertyInfos )
    {
        Func<object,object> func = x => propertyInfo.GetValue( x );

        map.Add( propertyInfo.Name , func );
    }

    // get the names by user-input
    var names = propertyInfos.Select( x => x.Name ).ToArray();

    // load the properties by name
    foreach( var testClass in testClasses )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( $"{testClass.Id} - {testClass.Name}" );

        foreach( var name in names )
        {
            var func = map[ name ];
            var value = func( testClass ); // this is 'bad' as it uses reflection every invokation

            Console.WriteLine( $"\t{name} = {value}" );
        }
    }
}
```

My question would be: can this Dictionary

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,Func<object,object>> {
    { "Id"      , x => ( x as TestClass ).Id    } ,
    { "Name"    , x => ( x as TestClass ).Name  } ,
};
```

be created automatically by just providing the Type (and without using reflection on each invokation)?

Comment: Note that if you do as you suggest, you'll filter the rows C#-side... You won't produce a SQL query that uses a `WHERE`. Your C# code will receive all the rows of the table and then filter them :-(

Comment: In general, how to do it "correctly" depends on how you do the queries to the DB... If you use an *Ado.NET* (`DbConnection` or `SqlConnection` with `DbCommand` or `SqlCommand`) and write queries with strings then there is a set of solutions. If you use Entity Framework, Linq-to-SQL, NHibernate, ??? there are other solutions.

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately I am required to load the record into memory, as I have to preprocess them before filtering (and I cannot change the underlying table representation or store the preprocessed versions in another table). Im curious if this is even possible, like a 'stored procedure for C# Funcs'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could gain something by removing the reflection from each call and doing it only once:

```
var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "row");

// load the map once
foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
    Func<object, object> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(par, propertyInfo.DeclaringType), propertyInfo), typeof(object)), par).Compile();
    map.Add(propertyInfo.Name, func);
}
```

I create a vary small expression tree that casts the parameter object to the "correct" type (`TestClass` in this case), calls the getter of the property and the convert the result to `object`.